# Hardmode terraria npc respawn

Tags: terraria-mobile

None of my pcs are respawning after hard mode my house is not damaged in any way it is exactly how I built it but it says someone wants to move in but does not move in it is not infected and there is no invasion going on. Even when no one dies the after hard mode npc won't move in.

Comment: Try going away from your house for a couple of minutes. If a NPC wants to move in, they'll eventually teleport in.

Comment: What does the game tell you when you check for valid housing?

Comment: I'm on mobile I can't check housing

Comment: Odds are it's a Truffle. They require a house in a surface Mushroom biome. See: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/249637/why-wont-this-npc-move-in

Comment: No one will respawn not my guide or nurse or arms dealer

Answer (score 0):

Wait for a day, they will respawn.